# How to convert part of a column to date in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

i have Pandas Data Frame in Python like below:

```
col1
------
00121088645
90110544547
02031134543
110588
```

- I need to take first 6 elements from each value in col1 and create date based on it and create new column "birthday_date" with this date
- If value in col1 starts with 00 it is 2000 not 1900, and for example 90 is 1990 not 1890 or any other. We calculate birthday date so it can only be 1900 + or 2000+ :)
- be aware! if in col1 value has not 11 elements value in col2 has to be "0"

So for example:

- 00121088645 = 2000-12-10
- 90110544547 = 1990-11-05
- 02031134543 = 2002-03-11

So as a result I need:

```
col1          birthday_date
-------------------------      
00121088645 | 2000-12-10
90110544547 | 1990-11-05
02031134543 | 2002-03-11
110588      | 0
```

Comment: For numbers up to 21, how do you know whether the year is 2010 or 1910, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `str` accessor to get the first 6 chars and then use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format='%y%m%d'` and `errors='coerce'`:

```py
df['birthday_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'].str[:6], format='%y%m%d', errors='coerce')

#           col1 birthday_date
# 0  00121088645    2000-12-10
# 1  90110544547    1990-11-05
# 2  02031134543    2002-03-11
# 3       110588           NaT
```

Chain `fillna(0)` to replace `NaT` with 0 if preferred:

```py
df['birthday_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'].str[:6], format='%y%m%d', errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Note that I'm assuming `col1` contains strings (otherwise there would not be any leading zeros).